# Jar file extract issue

Tags: maven, jar

I have a jenkins job which create an artifact jar with dependencies with maven. When I download the jar file from jenkins work space and try to extract it locally using

```
jar xvf jarfile-with-dependencies.jar
```

I got following error: **java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF\maven\org.slf4j (Access is denied)**

But when I package the jar file using same pom file configuration in my local for same project, I got no error and successfully extracted the jar file contents.

I have full access (read, write, delete, modify) for the folder in which I am extracting the jar file contents.

Comment: Can you make an an `unzip -t jarfile-with-dependencies.jar` on the jenkins packaged file...

Comment: @khmarbaise - that works perfectly fine - No errors detected. But we need to deploy jar file to aws lambda function which will use jar command for extracting the artifact.

Comment: I meant to show the list output of the above here in the post...